# How to save a list of file paths between sessions?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'd like to implement a bookmarks function in my app. I can handle everything besides saving and then loading the list of saved bookmarks. I plan to save the locations as Strings which contain the paths to the bookmarked directories.

The "Storage Options" page of the Developer Guide lists the available options, but doesn't really specify what the benefits of each one are.

What is the best practice for saving this sort of data between sessions?

Comment: It depends on what kind of usage you are expecting. Realistically speaking the average Joe won't create hundreds of bookmarks with your app. So using SharedPreferences will be fine for storing / retrieving your bookmarks as string set. If you want to play safe you should use an SQLite database instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `shared preferences` when you have small amount of data, more likely a name-value pair use when you want to save some preferences about the app.
- Use `Sqlite` when you have large amount of structured data. Like you have the names and grades of a Class then you must use a `SQLite`
- Use files for more large size of data like images, videos, xmls

I hope it will help you decide what you want. But in your case `Sqlite` is a best option.